shinobi installation err macOs: syntax error near unexpected token `('
hi i am installing shinobi in ninja way in macOS Sonoma 14.4.1 but getting this error:
jasimkhan@Jasims-MacBook-Air ~ % sudo su
sh-3.2# sh <(curl -s https://cdn.shinobi.video/installers/shinobi-install.sh)
sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh-3.2#

It appears your root account's shell is bash, but run under the name "sh"; this puts bash in a sh-compatibility mode where some features are turned off, including process substitution with <( ).

how can fix this
